# How do we suppress tshark default output

Tags: linux, tshark

How do we suppress tshark default output. Please see the given below sample output for more detail:

```
system@client:~$ sudo tshark -q -i eth0 -f "tcp" -a duration:3 -w /tmp/test.pcap
[sudo] password for system:
tshark: Lua: Error during loading:
 [string "/usr/share/wireshark/init.lua"]:45: dofile has been disabled
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
2 packets captured
system@client:~$
```

===================================================================

## Testbed:

Client <---------------> Server

## Code Sample:

```
        def execTShark(self,cmd):
            try:
                    self.SSHCONN.sendline('')
                    self.SSHCONN.expect('[#\$>]')
                    self.SSHCONN.maxread=20000
                    self.output = ""
                    self.SSHCONN.sendline( cmd )
                    while 1:
                            i       = self.SSHCONN.expect (['password', '[#\$>]'])
                            self.output       =       self.output + self.SSHCONN.before
                            if i==0:
                                    self.SSHCONN.sendline(self.password)
                            elif i==1:
                                    self.SSHCONN.sendline('')
                                    self.SSHCONN.expect (['[#\$>]', 'Capturing'])
                                    self.output       =       self.output + self.SSHCONN.before
                                    self.SSHCONN.sendline('')
                                    break
                    self.SSHCONN.expect('[#\$>]')
                    self.output       =       self.output + self.SSHCONN.before
                    print self.output
            except Exception as ex:
                    print("An exception occurred, " + str(ex))
                    return False
            return True
```

## Problem:

1.When i call the above mentioned function, execTShark with the cmd="sudo tshark -q -i eth0 -f "tcp" -a duration:3 -w /tmp/test.pcap &", sometime it failed, while waiting for this message "Capturing on eth0".

Comment: off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I am using pexpect to automate a testcase, but due to this message, it is causing my python script to fail. I don't know how do i suppress this message to make script work. Please suggest.

Comment: Then post a small test case along with relevant error messages.

Comment: I have updated my question with additional info. Please check it and let me know if you can find the issue and help me.

Comment: I have solved this issue, by doing
sudo tshark -q -i eth0 -f "tcp" -a duration:3 -w /tmp/test.pcap > /dev/null 2>&1 &